# Parse JSON in Scala using JSON4S

Tags: json, scala

I have some response data in JSON format:

```
{ "items" : 
    [
    {"commentId" : "28444760","userId" : "142607","userIP" : "","userName" : "Rock&#39;n&#39;Roll ","userAvatar" : "/i/default_userpic.png ","userIsBlock" : false,"userBanDate" : "",
    "userCountry" : "http://ikor.ill.in.ua/f/UA.gif","date" : "16.02.2017, 17:07","text" : "txt","rate" : 2,"isLikeExist" : false,"childComments" : []}
    ]
}
```

and I want to parse it to lists. 
For example, to extract `commentId` I use:

```
val js = parse(json)\\"items"
val commentId:List[String] = js\\"commentId"\ classOf[JString]
```

and I get list with id

when I tried parsing `date` I got:

```
List(16.02.2017, 17:24, 16.02.2017, 17:23)
```

How I can return the date list in the format List("date time")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case is:

```
val dateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy, HH:MM")
val date:List[java.util.Date] = (js\\"date").children.map(x=>dateFormat.parse(x.values.toString))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can parse date/times with a format specification:

```
def parseDT(s: String) = {
 val fmt = "dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"
 val df = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(fmt)
 java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(s, df)
}
```

So after you get the dates from JSON (as strings) parse them:
`val dates = datesFromJSON.map(parse(_))`

If all you want is to remove the comma from the date strings, you can do
`val dates = datesFromJSON.map(s => s.replaceAll(",",""))`

Comment: yes , but i need get date as string. At now, i can get few date as List(date , time, date, time)

Comment: for parse date i use val dateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM") dateFormat.parse(date)

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is from the legacy Java classes. Use the new classes from `java.time.format`